# Selecting / Grouping together MySqli data through joins

Tags: mysql

First and foremost, I do not have any code to back this at this point. I am trying to conceptualize an idea.

I have a database full of shows that each can have multiple genres, such as show A can be an action, adventure, drama. Typical, right? Right now, as I have my database set up to have columns such as genre_1, genre_2, genre_3. This is terrible, I know, which is why I am redoing it.

I am wanting to create a table full of genres, then have a table with the show information, then have a table to relate those two. So, the primary keys in the genre and show tables would be foreign keys in the genre-show table.

I'm pretty sure this is the best way to go about this one-to-many relationship.

My problem is, I'm uncertain of how I would, for say, list all shows that are in the action OR adventure genres, or list all shows that are in action AND adventure genres.

I'm fairly familiar with joins, but on my knowledge I can't figure out how I would query that.

Ultimately, what I am looking to do is be able to query my DB and say "Give me every show that has action and adventure genres" and then be on my way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One to many 101:

Main Table:

```
id (primary key, auto_increment), 
name, 
datecreated (datetimestamp), 
dateupdated (datetimestamp)
```

Many-to-one A

```
id (primary key, auto_increment),
main_id (foreign key)
name, 
datecreated (datetimestamp), 
dateupdated (datetimestamp)
```

Many-to-one B

```
id (primary key, auto_increment),
main_id (foreign key)
name, 
datecreated (datetimestamp), 
dateupdated (datetimestamp)
```

Now you may join up as many, Many-to-one tables as you need thusly:

```
select
  *
from
  main left join
  table_a on main.id = table_a.main_id left join
  table_b on main.id = table_b.main_id
where
  main.id = X
```

You will receive back many rows, but each row will have duplicates of the main object but include all many-to-ones.  This is called [Denormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).

Or you may prefer to do sub loops whereby you run one query to get your main objects, and then within a subloop for each many-to-one, you use the `main.id` to find the `main_id.id` rows that match your object.